# Converting dates in a feature collection to a previous date

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, date

I have a featureCollection with the dates for 2021. I would like to do a date conversion for this featureCollection to get the same dates in 2017. I have written the function above but it returns the error. How can I solve this?

```
//Date conversion
print(swarms)

//Converting data parameter 

function epoch2date(feature){
  var epoch = feature.get('STARTDATE');
  var date = ee.Date(epoch).format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  return feature.set('date', date);
}

var swarmDates = swarms.map(epoch2date);
print(swarmDates)


//Compute dates in 2017
function dates(feature){
  var date = swarmDates.get('date');
  var newDate = ee.Date(date).advance(-4, 'year').format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  return feature.set('newDate', newDate)
}

var dates2017 = swarms.map(dates);

print(dates2017)
```

The link to the code to is;https://code.earthengine.google.com/098d3ae0185833f573d8f3e372fc5160

Comment: What is the erro you get?

Comment: @JonasV this is the error I am getting FeatureCollection (Error)
Date: Parameter 'value' is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two typos in your code. In the function `dates` your are mistakenly calling `swarmDates` instead of `feature`. And for dates2017 you have to call map on `swarmDates` instead of `swarms`

```
//Compute dates in 2017
function dates(feature){
  var date = feature.get('date');
  var newDate = ee.Date(date).advance(-4, 'year').format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  return feature.set('newDate', newDate)
}

var dates2017 = swarmsDates.map(dates);

print(dates2017)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typos in the code. Now it works perfectly. Much appreciated!